# pre-emptive SJF With TimeQuantum

Tags: java

You have an array name, Process name, second array Process arrival time, and third Process burst time. And a variable time quantum. Write a Java program That has the shortest burst time. Subtract one from his burst time. Before subtracting, you must check every that the process has come or arrived; if not, then Subtraction cannot be done. If it comes, then you can subtract one from its burst time. Do this until all the burst times are zero. And if multiple Processes have equal burst times and they arrived, then minus time quantum from those equal processors' burst times. Print the process whose burst time is being subtracted. Do step by step.

Sample input: ("P1", 4, 5),("P2", 1, 6),("P3", 1, 6),("P4", 2, 4),("P5", 3, 3)
Sample output: P2 execute 2 unit, p3 execute 2, p5 execute 1, p5 execute 1, p5 execute 1,P2 execute 2 unit, p3 execute 2,P4 execute 2 unit, p2 execute 2,P3 execute 2 unit, p4 execute 2,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1.

import java.util.*;

public class ShortestJobFirst {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get the number of processes
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    // Create arrays to store the process names, arrival times, and burst times
    String[] name = new String[n];
    int[] arrivalTime = new int[n];
    int[] burstTime = new int[n];

    // Get the process names, arrival times, and burst times
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        name[i] = sc.next();
        arrivalTime[i] = sc.nextInt();
        burstTime[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    // Get the time quantum
    int timeQuantum = sc.nextInt();

    // Sort the processes by arrival time
    Arrays.sort(arrivalTime);

    // Create a queue to store the processes
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    // Initialize the current time to zero
    int currentTime = 0;

    // While there are still processes in the queue or not all processes have finished executing
    while (!queue.isEmpty() || Arrays.stream(burstTime).anyMatch(x -> x > 0)) {
        // If the queue is empty, add the first process to the queue
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            queue.add(0);
        }

        // Get the current process
        int currentProcess = queue.poll();

        // If the current process has arrived
        if (arrivalTime[currentProcess] <= currentTime) {
            // If the burst time of the current process is less than or equal to the time quantum
            if (burstTime[currentProcess] <= timeQuantum) {
                // Subtract the burst time of the current process from the current time
                currentTime += burstTime[currentProcess];

                // Set the burst time of the current process to zero
                burstTime[currentProcess] = 0;

                // Print the process whose burst time was subtracted
                System.out.println(name[currentProcess] + " execute " + burstTime[currentProcess] + " unit");

            } else {
                // Subtract the time quantum from the burst time of the current process
                burstTime[currentProcess] -= timeQuantum;

                // Print the process whose burst time was subtracted
                System.out.println(name[currentProcess] + " execute " + timeQuantum + " unit");

                // Add
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
I am expecting this output but not getting
Sample output: P2 execute 2 unit, p3 execute 2, p5 execute 1, p5 execute 1, p5 execute 1,P2 execute 2 unit, p3 execute 2,P4 execute 2 unit, p2 execute 2,P3 execute 2 unit, p4 execute 2,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1,p1 execute 1.

Comment: What is a "SJF"? What is a "TimeQuantum"?

Comment: Your code needs formatting.

Comment: Seems like you want us to finish your school work assignment. That is not the purpose of this site. Here you need to ask a specific question focused on a particular programming problem or technique.